# The meaning of tibbies?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "tibbies" in this context. The quote is from one of Richard Laymon's books:

> "You killed her, so you get first tibbies. So take the head. Everybody
>   does. 'cause the brain's the best part. So you take first tibbies on
>   the head, and give it to me."

I googled it and the results were mainly a dog breed which is not obviously how it is used in this book. I even checked Urban Dictionary but couldn't find an appropriate definition that would fit in this context.

Comment: Looks like a variation on [dibs](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dibs), sense 2....

Comment: Yeah, it could be because I had seen another usage while googling it that would fit that meaning perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @aytug2001 Don't be satisfied so easily! What's the book? Where is the author from and how old? Same for what the character speaking is supposed to be.

Comment: Richard Laymon - The woods are dark. 80 or 90's I guess? The character is talking about a Krull (a creature from the woods). Here's the second quote from the same writer that I had found while googling it: (this one's from One Rainy Night)

'I call first tibbies.' 'Bullshit.' 'Hey, you got Cyndi and Bud got Sheila. It's my turn.' 'Whoever finds her first,' Doug said.

See, it fits perfectly :)

Comment: the connection between dibs and tibbies is not clear, though.

Answer (score -1):

**(first) dibs (on something)**. [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dibs) an idiom

> slang The rights to something, or the rights to have first choice of
> something. "Dibs" are usually claimed verbally.

Literary uses of English are given poetic license.  This idiom ... is the idiomatic use of English, and in your example there is the variation 'tibbies'.

Comment: Do you have any listing for 'tibbies'? All this looks like is conjecture on your part that 'dibs' is relevant because it is similar.

Comment: Can you please support your claim that tibbies is a variant of dibs.